# linq find in which position is my object in List

Tags: c#, linq, position

kriteriji is type of `List<Kriteriji>`

```
var doc = kriteriji.Where(k => k.Ean == txtEan.Text
                     && k.PredmetObravnave == acPredmetObravnave.Text
                     && k.Tse == txtTse.Text
                     && k.DejanskaKolicina == Convert.ToInt32(txtKolicina.Text)
                     && k.KratekNazEnoteMere == acKNEnotaMere.Text
                     && k.OznakaLokacije == acOznakaLokacije.Text
                     && k.OznakaZapore == txtZapora.Text
                     && k.SarzaDob == txtSarzaDobavitelja.Text
                     && k.Sarza == txtSarza.Text
                     && k.DatumVelOd == datumOd
                     && k.DatumVelDo == datumDo).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now when I get `doc` how can I know in which position in `List<kriteriji>` is? I need to now if is in first, second,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx) method:

```
kriteriji.IndexOf(doc);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an overload for select that will take an index and a Kriteriji.

Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx).

Then you could select an anonymous object with an Index property and a Doc property. If you would use IndexOf this will cause another search throughout the list while you already have that data.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could create a (index , value) keyvaluepaire object at first and then retrive it like

```
        var doc = kriteriji.Select((value, index) => new { index, value })
            .Where(k => k.value.Ean == txtEan.Text
                 && k.value.PredmetObravnave == acPredmetObravnave.Text
                 && k.value.Tse == txtTse.Text
                 && k.value.DejanskaKolicina == Convert.ToInt32(txtKolicina.Text)
                 && k.value.KratekNazEnoteMere == acKNEnotaMere.Text
                 && k.value.OznakaLokacije == acOznakaLokacije.Text
                 && k.value.OznakaZapore == txtZapora.Text
                 && k.value.SarzaDob == txtSarzaDobavitelja.Text
                 && k.value.Sarza == txtSarza.Text
                 && k.value.DatumVelOd == datumOd
                 && k.value.DatumVelDo == datumDo).FirstOrDefault();
```

then you could get the index like

```
Console.WriteLine(doc.index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var position = kriteriji.IndexOf(doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the index with:

```
kriteriji.IndexOf(doc.First());
```

Comment: It looks like not <code>doc.First()</code>, but <code>doc</code> - because of it returns doc is an 1 element but not collection