# Find the position of a List Item in a List based upon specifice criteria using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

Something similar to [linq find in which position is my object in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209197/linq-find-in-which-position-is-my-object-in-list), except his accepted answer is evaluating at an object level.

Say I have

```
public interface IFoo{
    string text {get;set;}
    int number {get;set;}
}
```

and

```
public class Foo : IFoo{
    public string text {get;set;}
    public int number {get;set;}
}
```

Now I have a list collection of `IFoo` like so:

```
public IList<IFoo> Foos;
```

I want to write a method that brings back the index(es) of `Foos` based upon a property value and/ or values (for example, `text` or `number` in this case) so I can do something like:

```
var fooIndexes = Foos.GetIndexes( f => f.text == "foo" && f.number == 8 );
```

How would I write that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetIndices<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return items.Select( (item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
                     .Where(p => predicate(p.Item))
                     .Select(p => p.Index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s the non-LINQ implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetIndexes<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, 
    Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (T item in items)
    {
       if (predicate(item))
           yield return i;

       i++;
    }
}
```

In this case, this would probably be more efficient since it avoids the anonymous type initialization.